# Excel vba insert missing date for multiple type

Tags: vba, excel

I have been looking for vba codes to input missing date but I can't find any code that will work for my case
I currently have data like below:

```
Type.      Date.   
A         3/2/2018
A         3/3/2018
A         3/10/2018
A         3/28/2018
B         3/2/2018
B         3/3/2018
B         3/10/2018
B         3/28/2018
```

I was hoping for the result where for type A, the vba will insert the missing date (from 3/1/2018 until 3/31/2018) and then move on to type B and insert the missing date (from 3/1/2018 until 3/31/2018) and so on.

I have try below code however it stop when type A reach 3/31/2018

[Add missing dates VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723424/add-missing-dates-vba)

Comment: What do you mean by missing date? Is it always from 1 to last date of month as from your explanation?

Comment: The date from the original data can have missing date where for example it does not include weekends. I was trying to find out the vba code  to insert the those weekend date so the result data will have complete date from the beginin of the month until the end of the month. And repeatedly do the same thing for type B, and so on

Comment: From given data, then it will 31 `A` and 31 `B` in `Type` column and date will from 1 to 31 for each type `A` and `B`, right?

Comment: You can use a loop with EOMONTH fill to the end of each month. It will be a lot easier if your data is ordered.

Comment: Yes correct harun24hr :)