# Set reference to cells in column E

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code:

[Add missing dates VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723424/add-missing-dates-vba/36723912#36723912?newreg=39c69b9dde1f42248ac3da7203f0b58a)

```
Sub InsertMissingDates()

Dim i As Long
Dim RowCount As Long

i = 4

Do

If Cells(i, 1) + 1 < Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
    Rows(i + 1).Insert
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = Cells(i, 1) + 1
End If

If (Cells(i + 1, 1) = "") Then
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = Cells(i, 1) + 1
End If

i = i + 1

Loop Until Cells(i, 1).Value >= DateSerial(2016, 1, 30)

End Sub
```

How do I point to column E rather than it column A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the parameter on Cells function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells

On Cells function the second parameter:

```
1- A
2- B
3- C
4- D
5- E
```

So if you change your Code and use 5 instead of 1 it will work on cell E

```
Sub InsertMissingDates()

Dim i As Long
Dim RowCount As Long

i = 4

Do

If Cells(i, 5) + 1 < Cells(i + 1, 5) Then
    Rows(i + 1).Insert
    Cells(i + 1, 5) = Cells(i, 5) + 1
End If

If (Cells(i + 1, 5) = "") Then
    Cells(i + 1, 5) = Cells(i, 5) + 1
End If

i = i + 1

Loop Until Cells(i, 5).Value >= DateSerial(2016, 1, 30)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I get the following run-time error '13': Type Mismatch any ideas?

Comment: Ah no issues, i had the wrong column! thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter to determine the column:

```
Sub InsertMissingDates()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim WhichCol As String

    i = 4
    WhichCol = "D"

    Do
        If Cells(i, WhichCol) + 1 < Cells(i + 1, WhichCol) Then
            Rows(i + 1).Insert
            Cells(i + 1, WhichCol) = Cells(i, WhichCol) + 1
        End If

        If (Cells(i + 1, WhichCol) = "") Then
            Cells(i + 1, WhichCol) = Cells(i, WhichCol) + 1
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop Until Cells(i, WhichCol).Value >= DateSerial(2016, 1, 30)

End Sub
```